# How http proxy clients work

Tags: http, web, proxy

if an HTTP client reaches a website through a proxy (not reverse proxy) server, what are the actual HTTP request and its parameters that are sent from this client host to the internet?

for example: 

`Proxy Server: www.proxy.com:80
Target website: www.website.com:8081`

Does the HTTP client send the following Get request?

`Get http://www.proxy.com:80
Host: www.proxy.com:80`

OR

`Get http://www.website.com:8081
Host: www.website.com:8081`

if the first case is true, How can the proxy know what is the actual destination to forward this request?

otherwise, if the second is true, how can the request actually reach the proxy host machine?

Answer (score 4):

When you want to issue a GET request to `http://www.example.com:8081/index.html`, the browser connects to `www.example.com:8081` and sends the following request:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com:8081
```

Now when a proxy is configured, say `www.proxy.com:80`, the browser will connect to **`www.proxy.com:80`** instead, and issue the following request:

```
GET http://www.example.com:8081/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com:8081
```

So when a proxy is configured, the HTTP client connects to the proxy instead of to the target server, and sends the request using the absolute URI.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by: " the browser will connect to www.proxy.com:80 instead"?

how exactly can it connect to the proxy other than specifying the proxy host in the url or Host header?

Comment: It will connect to the proxy server over TCP, just like it would to a regular web server.

Comment: So there is a TCP setup first with (IP address of) the proxy. Once you have that connection the HTTP uses it to send HTTP requests to the target website.

Answer (score 2):

Http proxy server can read http headers. 
Whenever we use http proxy the destination address in the tcp packet(originating from client) has destination address of proxy server..
When the proxy server receives the tcp packet it can read the http headers(which is present in tcp packet payload) the http headers contains the actual destination for the packet.. using this information the http proxy server can forward the packet to actual destination.

Source : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_9.1.0/com.ibm.rational.ritpp.install.doc/topics/c_ritpp_advanced_proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

The client doesn't have to change the HTTP request for it to be sent to a proxy. It has to change the TCP headers.

The screenshot below shows a HTTP request sent from my browser to a proxy, as you can see nothing in the HTTP request itself specifies the proxy.

How this works is the browser/client will issue a HTTP GET request, which will then be forwarded to the TCP/IP stack and wrapped in a TCP header. The TCP header is where the destination is specified (proxy or otherwise).

[image]

Comment: _"The client doesn't change the HTTP request"_ - it does. HTTP debuggers who act as proxies just don't display this.

Comment: @CodeCaster - improved my answer